# Compare strings in templates

Tags: go-templates

I have the following template:

```
{{if . eq "login failed"}}
<span class="text-error">Incorrect username or password</span>
{{else if . eq "login success"}}
<span class="text-success">You have successfully logged in!</span>
{{end}}
```

I am passing a string when I execute the template.

However, I get the following error:

```
executing "login.html" at <.>: can't give argument to non-function .
```

How do I compare the strings within the template?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[`eq` is function](https://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Functions), not an operator. It is called with the form: `eq <x> <y>` (not `<x> eq <y>`).

You can fix your template by moving the operands from the the sides of `eq` to after it:

```
{{if eq . "login failed"}}
<span class="text-error">Incorrect username or password</span>
{{else if eq . "login success"}}
<span class="text-success">You have successfully logged in!</span>
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 26):

**To compare if two strings equal :**

```
{{ if eq .Status "Approved" }}
       ...Do something
{{ else }} 
       ...Do something else
{{ end }}
```

**To compare if two strings not equal :**

```
  {{ if ne .Status "" }}  // If status is not empty 
           ...Do something
  {{ else }} 
           ...Do something else
  {{ end }}
```

There are more golang HTML template directives here at : https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Actions